# How do you make the status bar appear iOS

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistatusbar, ios7-statusbar

This is getting very frustrating for me because I can't get the status bar to appear in my app. Everything related as far as UI is done on storyboard. when i set my status bar:inferred, top bar: inferred in my navigation controller, the status bar shows up fine. However, I do not want the top bar to appear as it interferes with my layout, so I set the top bar to none, which results in no top bar or status bar.

How can I just make the status visible without affecting my layout? (auto-layout is enabled)

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to show the status bar, but hide the navigation bar?

Comment: yes, is this not possible?

Comment: Did you try returning `NO` from `prefersStatusBarHidden` in your `UIViewController`?

Comment: yes, just did but same result.

Answer (score 0):

So I did more googling and research, turns out I just had to add View controller-based status bar appearance as the key and the value as NO in the .plist file